# mySQLi is not SELECTing data appropriately

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am converting from mysql_ to mysqli.  Doing some tutorials.  Not getting much success despite reading and googling the subject.  I have attempted a prepared statement but it keeps outputting 0 results (ie. now_rows =0 ).  When I manually query the mySQL table there are a number of results that return.

mySQLI 5.0.96 is enabled

```
<?
include("conn.php");
// SELECT sql query
$sql = "SELECT id, rotation, assignedRad FROM sched_main WHERE thedate = ?"; 
// perform the query and store the result
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$thedate='2013-01-02';
$query->bind_param('s', $thedate);
$query->execute();
// if the $query contains at least one row
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row from $query
  while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<br /> id: '. $row['id']. ' - name: '. $row['rotation']. ' - pass: '.     $row['assignedRad'];
  }
  $query->free();
}
else {
  echo '0 results';
}
?>
```

Question 2:  is there an easy way to debug mysqli?  Using mysql_query I would simply echo $sql; to see what the SELECT statement looks like as part of my debugging process.
Thanks in advance

UPDATED:

here is a snippet of the updated code as suggested below:

```
$query->bind_param('s', $thedate);
if (!$query->execute()) {
  die($conn->error);
}
$query->store_result();
// if the $query contains at least one row
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row from $query
  while($row = $query->fetch()) {
    echo '<br /> id: '. $row['id']. ' - name: '. $row['rotation']. ' - pass: '. $row['assignedRad'];
  }
  $query->mysqli_free();
}
else {
  echo '0 results';
}
```

Now it outputs with the array $row values as no value:

```
id: - name: - pass: 
id: - name: - pass: 
id: - name: - pass:
```

.. etc...

I also get
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::mysqli_free()

and when I try free() I get:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::free()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the debugging part, but you may need to store the result of the DB execution call before calling `$query->num_rows`. Also, you may want to check if the preparation and execution were successful.

```
...
if (!$query = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
  die($conn->error);
}
$thedate='2013-01-02';
$query->bind_param('s', $thedate);
if (!$query->execute()) {
  die($conn->error);
}
$query->store_result();
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
  ...
}
```

See the PHP doc for more info on [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) and [`error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)